# json_decode returns null and bool false

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode, utf-16

I have code:

```
    <?php $json = '[{"title":" \\ud83c\\uddf7\\ud83c\\uddfa \\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u043a\\u043e\\u0435 \\u043a\\u0430\\u0437\\u0438\\u043d\\u043e #1 
\\ud83c\\uddf7\\ud83c\\uddfa ","desc":"\\u0422\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u043a\\u043e 
\\u0437\\u0430\\u0440\\u0435\\u0433\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0440\\u0438\\u0440\\u0443\\u0439\\u0441\\u044f \\u0438 \\u0438\\u0433\\u0440\\u0430\\u0439 
\\u043f\\u0435\\u0440\\u0432\\u044b\\u0439 \\u0440\\u0430\\u0437 \\u0437\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430\\u0448 
\\u0441\\u0447\\u0451\\u0442","icn":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/ic?sid=2&data=0eikgji0Ck2EKXJkLTJfLie%2FKy%2FvWYZiVPrhxIOQsl6VkyioGiy%2B4DYdpqaaMXlM5dVPkQoRzngoPAlvQ3w1pREOxlMjuR7DQHq6Yz0oA7ZXT9CV1ut2ICfrquV9FoQ%2BjltIeJAcUnB%2BTMvTjn%2BGs1lvh5bOIUUXYa0tIJCe%2BJe2LX38OpOLAJ%2B7U1h12rvXozelMT5SGd67wzUnFI7er3gJycSu7WAH72sUTT%2FZ%2F3nJQOZBOMHY8WyX8jqel5Mo8BMNLzIXHyjpA%2BiZlgYsEg%3D%3D","img":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/im?sid=2&data=ZQqgvmU6z8ZR4RPBdAhPWcdkbt5b%2BWp435ln18YHYo1SXskUGSiZhGwhvcXnWECjuteCzRQRWIhfYTUDd4wLcUq7jKaYn55gJUbQZr3UM6SAx2dKKXUVQVmstTsIdXma7gZ57%2B8L58uusM7pf8HpgSTreH8rjJIX%2BQEruq544CQQF%2FTNxTpCAesrBgQpkUOL76hSB%2F0Eaw3yYO0mDUDR6zKLXkDo6cxruIRrER05RSFJVtlFr3ihmDZHJQZnl%2FO6","url":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/clpsh?sid=2&d=1&data=h3OP98W8RXI52WXh0xUpzzPCqkn%2Boc1q7OZh2tb7pLxLU4il0MNlbTTRR%2FQJ3Ryj98kKbM2eOgq%2FVtMBpmy4huEGwavyp41rQdZTT%2Fjdsu0QcYNMwUiNBH4mifSNaIzMTDYTeB9hZ8BPwGw%2F171wk2af2qmrmLi7e13XtfK%2BFpZltozDNAqS%2BDJkvH3SVKJHo8TkGjb2FQonQoXeVXqfp6jp2MYLqp%2FOFf6dOcERVM%2Ff%2FYBgEZ2E%2FpzuMZSywxPt49sveDcfOE%2F9LOjBu6%2BU1XymVQdknq%2B0MzuJAd6Eq8%2FH4q%2F%2B7dlgvivqQm30C%2FvhG%2FfGSYQPEY%2BHdzAJZ%2FStRjZmMtGhsqHbMkGENTil4bzlo8VvMW6H2yLPpVVw8Eqw86jXlndl7qPusmT4W4VUVQzMEnKgDbiJFPGy45vE%2B3QOCqafNoCq90X7U%2FLlvr9Gxdox8qAUyhAMbqJU5p0GYlMk6iJDD3GaG%2FqAZN5hzM0%3D","price":"0.0055"}]'; 
$json = json_decode($json, true); var_dump($json);
echo '<br>'; 
echo json_last_error();
?>
```

It returns null and if I check JSON for errors it returns `bool(false)`. What is wrong? Online decoders are decoding json normally. JSON is advertisment I'm using for test.

I've been searching for issue for hours. I've deleted urls from json, checking if another jsons are working on site (they work). IDK what to do

Comment: What does `json_last_error()` return?

Comment: jsonlint.com says the JSON is valid.

Comment: WFM: https://3v4l.org/JA4jc

Comment: @Barmar returns 3.

Comment: @Sammitch I know that JSON is right. You can check what site returns https://1survey.cc/wp-content/themes/tafri-travel/assets/js/superbanner.php

Comment: That's `JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded`. So maybe there's a problem with one of the Unicode characters. Although that should cause `JSON_ERROR_UTF16`

Comment: @Barmar What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Since I can't actually see anything wrong, I don't know.

Comment: Are you actually creating the JSON with a string literal, or are you getting it as data from somewhere else?

Comment: @Barmar I took this JSON like example. I'm not using data from other sites. Code that you can see above is full code of file.

Comment: I pasted that code into a PHP file and ran it, and I got the same output as in Sammitch's link.

Comment: @Barmar I've solved question. Thanks for helping me finding error code. I will post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $json); $array = json_decode($json, true);
```

I should `preg_replace` before decoding JSON

Comment: Ideally you should find why there are control characters/rogue bytes in the JSON data and fix the thing that is doing that.